# Java 5 Does not validate DTD

Tags: java, validation, applet, dtd

I am working with a vendor applet, The applet works fine with JRE 1.4.2_X and 1.6.X but fails on every version of 1.5.X. Running with 1.6 is not an option due to another application conflict that does not play nice with Java 6.

The issue I believe is that the DTD is not being validated. This is causing the "not declared" problem and the resulting nullpointer.

```
 Error: Fri Aug 28 11:21:29 EDT 2009 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 
 Element type "UserSessionList" is not declared.
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried changing the default validation class but the problem remains unchanged.

```
 -Djavax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://relaxng.org/ns/structure
 /1.0=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory
```

Is there another validation I can use for this?

I don't really have the option of modifying the code the applet is beyond end of life from the vendor so getting support from them is unlikely. So any workarounds cannot involve changing code since we do not own it.

Comment: Point #1: JDK 1.5 does validate DTD's; I have a bunch of programs that would fail if it doesn't.

Comment: Point #2: the fact that it's saying an element type isn't declared ins a strong indication that it is in fact validating against a DTD, and either the XML has an element that isn't part of that DTD, or the DTD is not internally consistent (haven't looked to see the cause of that error message).

Comment: Point #3: the Sun JDK (and JRockit also, I believe) already uses Xerces. So unless you have a specific bug that was fixed in the Xerces distribution and not the JDK distribution, setting a different validator is not going to help you.

Comment: Point #4: schema validation is handled differently than DTD validation. Which are you using?

Comment: This isn't my code so unless I start decompiling classes all over I am not sure I can answer all the questions. I have a lack of in depth knowledge aroudn validation. 

I cannot figure out why this works fine in 1.6 but fails in 1.5. I tried using the 1.6 endorsed jaxp jars within 1.5 but I get the same error. 

Since this is 100% reproducible on 1.5 I dont think its something crazy thats coming through in the xml thats not in the dtd but that for some reason the dtd isnt even being loaded. Is there any way to verify? 

How can I tell whether I am using schema or dtd validation?

Comment: Start by looking at the XML. If it contains a DOCTYPE that specifies a SYSTEM or PUBLIC identifier, then chances are that it's DTD-validated. Otherwise it's probably Schema-validated. Or maybe it's not validated at all, and you're seeing an exception thrown by the handler code. Look at the XML again, and see if there's a UserSessionList element. Look at the exception stack trace, to see where it's being thrown. And yes, you might have to decompile some code, particularly if the company that sold you this applet isn't supporting it.

Comment: Why are you asking for relaxng and then specifying the class for XML Schema?

Why do you think that this is DTD rather than XMLSchema-related? Perhaps 1.5 is actually paying attention to some of these options ands 1.4 wasn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a current version of Xerces into the classspath, and get rid of all of those -D's. The SPI in Xerces will take over all of this and might behave better.

Comment: I will try and grab the xml, I don't think I remember seeing it in the snifer log. I didn't expect relaxng to work really, I am just trying to get this to do something different. This applet fails 100% of the time on 1.5. I was mainly trying to to figure out what the difference was between 1.5 and 1.6 that was causing the failure. Will post the xml when I get it. Reproducing this as a poja would not be easy as I don't own the source but with the xml maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the applet with all the existing code unmodified and specify which version of Java it executes under. You do this by declaring a `classid` parameter with the applet, like so:

```
<OBJECT
    classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0014-0002-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA"
    width="200" height="200">
    <PARAM name="code" value="Applet1.class">
</OBJECT>
```

There are different `classids` for the last four major releases of Java

**1.3** use CAFEEFAC-0013-0001-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA
**1.4** use CAFEEFAC-0014-0002-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA
**1.5** use CAFEEFAC-0015-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA
**1.6** use CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA

The caveat is that the client machine must have that version of Java installed, but the JREs are still available on Sun's site. More information here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/family-clsid.html

You can therefore mandate that your applet runs only 1.4, and it will not matter if the end user has another version of Java installed, as long as they have a 1.4 to run your applet.

Comment: I understand what your saying with the classid's. However with 1.5 installed it will refuse to run a JRE outside of that family. You can put in a registry change to turn off secure static versioning but this breaks 1 of the other 3 applets on the client machine. I can load up 1.6 and that will allow an older JRE to run after passing a security prompt but 1.6 also breaks the other applets. If I can just get this to work with 1.5 I can run all the applets off that just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might have been a bug present in Xerces when used with Java 1.5. See the last comment on this [Tomcat bug.](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40507#c7)